# git ls-files --stage shows files even after committing

Tags: git, indexing, stage

I'm after git command that shows all files currently residing inside staging area (is it the same as index?).

First I removed all files from index:

```
$ git rm --cached *
rm 'newfile'
rm 'os-list.txt'
rm 'remote_stuff'
rm 'removethis'
```

Now I check files in index:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 07e6e472cc75fafa944e2a6d4b0f101bc476c060 0       .gitignore
```

You can see only .gitignore file is left.

We then change the content of newfile. Then we add newfile to index.

```
$ git add newfile
```

Check the status:

```
$ git status -s
M  newfile
D  os-list.txt
D  remote_stuff
D  removethis
?? os-list.txt
?? remote_stuff
?? removethis
```

We can see newfile is now in index.

Now we expect staging area to be empty when we commit the files.

```
$ git commit -m "TEST333"
[master 0adab53] TEST333
 4 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 13 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 os-list.txt
 delete mode 100644 remote_stuff
 delete mode 100644 removethis
```

But even after commit we see newfile is still in staging area:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 07e6e472cc75fafa944e2a6d4b0f101bc476c060 0       .gitignore
100644 76abab2928bdd7dfe157109666023bb0c5e4c465 0       newfile
```

But if we check status we see there's nothing in staging area:

```
$ git status -s
?? os-list.txt
?? remote_stuff
?? removethis
```

Well, what I'm after is the command to show all files in staging area. The command `git ls-files --stage` is returning output that I don't understand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now we expect staging area to be empty when we commit the files.

That's your error.  Don't expect this!

> ... if we check status we see there's nothing in staging area

`git status` does not show you what is in the index / staging-area.  Instead, for each file, it *compares* what's in the index / staging-area to:

- what's in the `HEAD` commit: if different, the file is "staged for commit"; and
- what's in the work-tree: if different, the file is "not staged for commit"

—which is why a file can be *both* "staged for commit" *and* "not staged for commit".  That just means that the *index* copy, the one you see with `git ls-files --stage`, differs from *both of the other two copies*.

Every file has *three active copies*.<sup>1</sup>  When all three are *the same*, `git status` says nothing.  When some of the copies of file *F* differ, `git status` tells you about file *F*.  That's all there really is to it, here.

The index / staging-area holds, at all times,<sup>2</sup> what you plan (or Git plans) to put in your *next* commit.  That's why you have to update it after changing the work-tree copy: so that what Git plans to put in the *next* commit will match the work-tree copy.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, it's *up to* three copies, since you can have one or two copies missing.  A file is *tracked* if and only if there is a copy of it in the index (even if it's in the `HEAD` commit, it's only tracked if it's *also* in the index).  A work-tree file is *untracked* if it exists and is not in the index.  (Hence, after `git rm --cached`, a file that is in `HEAD` and in the work-tree is both about-to-be-deleted, and untracked, at the same time.)

<sup>2</sup>See footnote 1, and then see the conflicted merge case.  During a conflicted merge, the index holds up to *three* copies of each file: the merge base copy, the `--ours` copy, and the `--theirs` copy.  If you add in the `HEAD` copy and the work-tree copy, this means that during conflicted merges, there are up to *five* active copies of any one file.